# perl script argument contains double quotas "

Tags: perl, command-line-arguments, argument-passing, perl-data-structures

I have a perl script that receives 3 arugments.

First argument is very long and contains spaces and quotes and I actually don't know what size to expect it could be any size .  To separate my arguments I use ":" sign.

See example:
./my_script.pl 2MT5 4XAW KEAR  TTRR YYMM "TEMP 2012 FEB 01":Single:123.x

The problem is that I lose double quotes and spaces.See output :

```
LOG The 1st input is:2MT54XAWKEARTTRRYYMMTEMP 2012 FEB 01

LOG Type is:Single

LOG Version is:123.x
```

My Code :

```
open (FD, ">file2.txt");

print FD @ARGV;

close FD;

my $str1=`cat file2.txt`;

my @argv_values = split(':',$str1);

$new_str = $argv_values[0];

$type = $argv_values[1];

$ver = $argv_values[2];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Perl program does NOT receive 3 arguments, it receives 6 arguments. Simply print them out to see for yourself:

```
perl -le 'print for @ARGV' 2MT5 4XAW KEAR TTRR YYMM "TEMP 2012 FEB 01":Single:123.x
```

Your first argument (2MT5) is not "very long" it is only 4 characters.

You do not have a Perl problem, you have a shell problem. The shell splits args on spaces and processes double quotes. If you don't want it to do that, then you must quote any args that contain spaces or quotes:

```
./my_script.pl '2MT5 4XAW KEAR TTRR YYMM "TEMP 2012 FEB 01":Single:123.x'
```

Comment: Thank you, single quote helped me

Comment: Thanks, I was facing similar problem - it turned out I had shell problem, like you've said @tadmc

Answer (score 3):

It is the shell discarding those characters. Pass arguments properly (which includes quoting any which contain spaces, and escaping any quotes inside) and that won't be a problem:

```
./my_script.pl "2MT5 4XAW KEAR TTRR YYMM \"TEMP 2012 FEB 01\"" "Single" "123.x"
```

Then you don't need to mess around with splitting and joining. You'll have the arguments properly organised in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

- Of *course* you lose the double quotes. That's standard *NIX command line behavior, where double quotes indicates that you want the stuff inside them treated as one argument.
- And when you `print` a list of items, they are going to be concatenated *simply*.

The simplest way to do what you're intending is to `print "@ARGV";` because the default list separator, *for interpolated lists*, is a single space.

Comment: Thank you . Your answer helped me to understand the problem.